# Why do we have to provide WSGI_APPLICATION variable in Django settings

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-wsgi

I'm a beginner Django developer so if this question doesn't make sense please forgive me.

We provide a variable called `WSGI_APPLICATION` in django settings along with `ROOT_URLCONF` and some other settings variables. and we provide settings file path  in wsgi.py file as well,

```
import os
import django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGSS_MODULE", "<settings_file_path>")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

So you see, its a two way connection.right?

I mean path of settings file in wsgi file and path of wsgi file in settings file. so why do we have to do this.

as per my understanding path of settings file in wsgi file should be good enough and we dont need that extra variable in django settings?

ultimately the wsgi file is the starting point of django application, right?

PLease correct me wherever I'm wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Ultimately the wsgi file is the starting point of django application, right?*

Not necessarily. The [documentation for `WSGI_APPLICATION`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#wsgi-application) explains what this setting is for:

> The full Python path of the WSGI application object that Django’s built-in servers (e.g. `runserver`) will use.

Any server you set up has to know where the WSGI file is. If you're using an external server it will look in its own settings. If you're using Django's development server, it will check Django's settings. So the circularity you noticed is a consequence of the fact that the Django application can be started in a number of different ways.

Comment: What exactly you mean by  "the Django application can be started in a number of different ways."

Comment: @user5319825: Different web servers will all have their own way of configuring WSGI and starting Django. The way `runserver` does it is by looking in at the `WSGI_APPLICATION` setting, whereas Apache with mod_wsgi, say, [has its own configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/). You can also use a Django application without WSGI or a server at all, if you don't need to serve HTTP requests.

Comment: "You can also use a Django application without WSGI or a server at all, if you don't need to serve HTTP requests" how?

Comment: @user5319825: You could write a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/), or just write your own script and call [`django.setup()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.setup).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, wsgi.py plays a role of pointing to where your django project is, for WAS like Apache or something else.

Therefore wsgi.py starts outside of django, it needs django settings.