# How to run wsgi along the side of the daphne ASGI for django channels

Tags: django, wsgi, django-channels, daphne

I am using Django channels in my project using using official Django `channels v2`, my simple channels app is completed and working  fine if run `python manage.py runserver` but I want to run Django channels on a different port so I am now using daphne. When I use `daphne` with run command `my_project.asgi:application --port 8001` it works fine on 8001 port

```
INFO     Starting server at tcp:port=8001:interface=127.0.0.1
INFO     HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
```

and if I also run `python manage.py runserver` in another terminal at the same time it works fine. Now both channels on port `8001` and Django on `8000` port works as expected but my runserver command runs my application as ASGI/Channels instead of wsgi development server,

```
Starting ASGI/Channels version 2.2.0 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

instead of

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

settings.py

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'my_project.routing.application'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'my_project.wsgi.application'
```

If I debug any function in `views.py` request, it is ASGI request instead of Django wsgi request

```
asgi.py
import os
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings")
django.setup()
application = get_default_application()
```

My questions are as follows:

1. How can I get Django WSGI request instead of ASGI request in my normal function view request(like `def index(request)`) or if we install django channels every request become ASGI request?
2. what is the use of the python mange.py runworker command

Answer (score 3):

Like you can read here: https://asgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

> ASGI (Asynchronous Server Gateway Interface) is a spiritual successor
>   to WSGI, intended to provide a standard interface between
>   async-capable Python web servers, frameworks, and applications.
>
> Where WSGI provided a standard for synchronous Python apps, ASGI
>   provides one for both asynchronous and synchronous apps, with a WSGI
>   backwards-compatibility implementation and multiple servers and
>   application frameworks.

so answer for your question nr 1 is: `Yes, all requests will be ASGI`.

Question nr 2 - it's a command to run multiple workers to process your channel requests in asynchronous way https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/1.x/deploying.html#run-worker-servers

Comment: for question 1 if answer is yes then how third party apps will behave they were expecting django request right so from now onwards if i send the ASGI request(or instance) can they break??

Comment: or if yes then WSGI_APPLICATION is completely waste right?

Comment: ASGI request has all attributes that normal django request has so this is not a problem, it should be transparent for you.`WSGI_APPLICATION` is necessary for `runserver` command https://stackoverflow.com/a/36107047/2156813

Comment: yes boss and even if i comment out the code WSGI_APPLICATION in settings file my application and runserver working fine

Comment: @pako can you also see this my problem is also the similar one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59527805/problem-in-running-asgi-environments-while-deploying-app-django-rest?noredirect=1

Comment: Same question, quite green to Django. Installed channels, and now I can't seem to start my Django development server. runserver starts channels ASGI server, How can I run Django development server like it ran previously when I was not using channels?

Comment: @AdityaSingh provide more details. Why you cannot run development server?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @pawelbylina, but I figured it out. There was an issue in my routing.py file. It's working fine now.